# First day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello I am trying the alter this function to return the date of the first day of the week which I want to be Monday.The problem is when the input date is Sunday it returns the following Monday instead of the previous one.For example it should yield Input->Output given

```
2013-06-11 -> 2013-06-10
2013-06-16 -> 2013-06-10
```

Since Sunday is the only problem I added a case

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GetFirstDayOfWeek]
( @pInputDate    DATETIME )
RETURNS DATETIME

BEGIN

SET @pInputDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @pInputDate, 111)

 CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @pInputDate) = 'Sunday' THEN RETURN DATEADD(DD, -5- DATEPART(DW, @pInputDate),
              @pInputDate) ELSE RETURN DATEADD(DD, 2- DATEPART(DW, @pInputDate),
              @pInputDate) END

END
```

Problem is I get an error, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Case'.Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `RETURN` before the `CASE` statement, not in it.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GetFirstDayOfWeek]
( @pInputDate    DATETIME )
RETURNS DATETIME

BEGIN

SET @pInputDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @pInputDate, 111)

RETURN CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @pInputDate) = 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(DD, -5- DATEPART(DW, @pInputDate),
              @pInputDate) ELSE DATEADD(DD, 2- DATEPART(DW, @pInputDate),
              @pInputDate) END

END
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8161c/1).

Answer (score 2):

Day 0 of the SQL calendar is a Monday:

```
select datename(dw, 0);
```

Armed with this knowledge, we can easily do the math, just divide by 7, take the floor and multiply back by 7:

```
declare @d datetime = '20130611';
select dateadd(day, floor(cast(@d as int) / 7.00) * 7.00, 0);
set @d = '20130616';
select dateadd(day, floor(cast(@d as int) / 7.00) * 7.00, 0);
set @d = getdate();
select dateadd(day, floor(cast(@d as int) / 7.00) * 7.00, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also a setting in Sql Server - `DATEFIRST` which set the first day of the week (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)).

```
set datefirst 1 -- or @varDateFirst
go
```

will set monday as the first day of week (in U.S. default value is 7). So you can set this variable when you need it and set it back after.
Here's a [modified Ian Preston sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/587e8/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GetFirstDayOfWeek]
( @pInputDate    DATETIME )
RETURNS DATETIME

BEGIN

SET @pInputDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @pInputDate, 111)

declare @retDate datetime

set @retDate = CASE DATENAME(dw, @pInputDate) 
        WHEN 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(DD, -5- DATEPART(DW, @pInputDate),@pInputDate) 
        ELSE DATEADD(DD, 2- DATEPART(DW, @pInputDate), @pInputDate) 
END

return @retDate
END
```